# Azure Service Bus Brokered Message pump, awaiting multiple message types

Tags: generics, azureservicebus

I have a message pump that looks like this:

```
public class MessagePump<T> where T : class
    {
        public async Task Run( string inQueue, IMessageProcessor<T> processor, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var connectionString = Settings.ServiceBusConnectionString;
            var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
            var client = factory.CreateQueueClient(inQueue);
            var msgOptions = new OnMessageOptions
            {
                AutoComplete = false,
                MaxConcurrentCalls = 5,
                AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
            };
            await Task.Run(() =>
            client.OnMessageAsync(
              async message =>
              {
                  await OnReceived(message, processor);
                  await message.CompleteAsync();
              }, msgOptions),
              cancellationToken);
        }
        static async Task OnReceived(BrokeredMessage brokeredMessage, IMessageProcessor<T> processor)
        {
            var message = brokeredMessage.GetBody<T>();
            try
            {
                await processor.Process(message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var er = new ErrorLog();
                await er.Create(new {error = e.Message});
            }

        }
    }
```

It is called from my stateless service in Azure Service Fabric

```
internal sealed class Core : StatelessService
    {
        public Core(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        { }


        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[0];
        }

        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var inQueue = Settings.CoreQueue;
            await new MessagePump<Message>().Run(inQueue, new Processor(), cancellationToken);

        }
    }
```

How do I create a message pump that handles more than one type of message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

1. Encode all of your types as part of one container type (e.g. derive them all from one base class, or put them all into properties of the container type). Always deserialize this container, and then handle it based on its content.
2. Put the type of the message into metadata (e.g. `ContentType` property of `BrokeredMessage`. Deserialize to a specific type after reading this metadata.
3. Call `GetBody` which just returns a byte array, and handle deserialization yourself. Might be the only option if you don't control the sending party.

Comment: I think #2 is the best solution!! (given there is capability to design the sender)  #1 creates a big mess